# having trouble with pan-os-python sdk and pulling list of security policies

Tags: python, automation

im a network engineer by trade, but trying to be more devops like, forgive me if im missing obvious concepts, im still learning.

here is my code:

```
from panos import panorama
from panos.policies import PreRulebase
from panos.policies import SecurityRule




device = 'my panorama name'
auth_key = 'my api key'
devicegroup = 'my device group'  

# This defines how we will connect to panorama
mypanorama = panorama.Panorama(device, api_key=auth_key)

# This defines the device group we will be connecting to
palo_device_group = panorama.DeviceGroup(devicegroup)
mypanorama.add(palo_device_group)
# This defines that were going to be in the PreRulebase since these are panorama managed fw
rulebase = PreRulebase
palo_device_group.add(rulebase)

existing_policies = SecurityRule.refreshall(palo_device_group)
```

when debugging, the above object (existing_policies)  ends up being blank

im going to be migrating multiple device group security policies off this existing panorama to a new panorama, so i wanted to extract tags, service objects, address objects, service groups, and address groups then migrate (push) them to a new panorama. ( instead of manually moving it all).  I have been successful on everything up to this point, but im missing somethin ( in my opinion ) on the inheritance of the pan-os-python sdk as it pertains to PreRulebase and SecurityRule

Comment: i found my error by updatig the following code: '''existing_policies = SecurityRule.refreshall(rulebase)'''